# Use last value with operations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate, grouping

Let's assume I have a table in SQL Server called Budget_Spend like this [image: Original table]

I know, with proper group by, sum and order by reach the next table (it's pretty obvious) [image: objective table]

However, I don't how to replicate "Aviable" column, constructed following the logic:

- For the first month, it's Budget - Spend - Taxes
- For the following months is computed like PREVIOUS(Aviable)-CURRENT(Spend)-CURRENT(Taxes)

I've tried to use LAG function without succes (most of my tries didn't run due to syntax problems).

Any idea of doing? I imagine I need LAG and maybe a CASE in order to get the first value.

This is the DDL for creating the table

```
/* CREATE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE Budget_Spend(
Month DOUBLE,
Budget DOUBLE,
Spend DOUBLE,
Taxes DOUBLE);

/* INSERT */
INSERT INTO Budget_Spend(Month, Budget, Spend, Taxes) VALUES
(1, 1000, 75, 11.25);


INSERT INTO Budget_Spend(Month, Budget, Spend, Taxes) VALUES
(1, 1000, 25, 3.75);

INSERT INTO Budget_Spend(Month, Budget, Spend, Taxes) VALUES
(2, 1000, 200, 30);

INSERT INTO Budget_Spend(Month, Budget, Spend, Taxes) VALUES
(3, 1000, 150, 22.5);

INSERT INTO Budget_Spend(Month, Budget, Spend, Taxes) VALUES
(4, 1000, 10, 1.5);

INSERT INTO Budget_Spend(Month, Budget, Spend, Taxes) VALUES
(4, 1000, 10, 1.5);
```

Comment: work out the GROUP values for Month in a sub query, as part of a CTE - then use LAG on a query of the CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need window function :

```
select bs.*, 
      Budget - sum(Spend + Taxes) over (order by month) as Available 
from (select month, Budget, sum(Spend) as Spend, sum(Taxes) as Taxes
      from Budget_Spend bs
      group by month, Budget
     ) bs;
```